# Infinite __getitem__ calls during NumPy array assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of class instances, which have a `__getitem__` and a `__len__` method implemented. However, when I try to create a NumPy array out of this list with an empty array and the `[:]` operator, `__getitem__` of the first list element is stuck in an infinite call stack. When I remove `__len__` it works.
I have created a MWE below:

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self, cid):
        self.id = cid

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return 1

obj_list = [A(1), A(4), A(2)]

test = np.empty(len(obj_list), dtype="object")
test[:] = obj_list
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT:** The behaviour stays the same, no matter what I return in `__getitem__`

Comment: Are you sure it’s infinite, have you counted it?  But seriously, are you surprised given your definition of `__getitem__` (where an instance of `A` contains itself, which contains itself, which contains itself, which contains itself, ...)

Comment: Can you please post the traceback of the error you get? You can omit  intermediate recurring calls from the traceback if your interpreter does not.

Comment: @donkopotamus : I have printed `item` and it increases continuously. Yes, I would agree with you, but you can also return 1 in `__get_item__` and it shows the same behaviour. @MisterMiyagi : There is no error thrown (I have quit the program after 1 min).

Comment: @clax then your supposed test case with `__getitem__` returning `1`, not `self`, is the interesting one ... you should add **that** code and evidence.  The code as it stands is unsurprising.

Comment: @donkopotamus : Sorry, you are right. I agree with the recursive calls on `self`, so I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define both `__len__` and `__getitem__` on a type, then that type looks like a container, or **sequence**.

Naturally, `numpy` attempts to look inside this sequence.  But inside this sequence are objects that look like sequences ... you can see where this is going.

In short, you are asking `numpy` to populate a (recursively) infinite dimensional array.  It is not ending well.

———

Your question has now changed ... your problem now is that your type claims to be a container, but does not implement bounds.  Try defining

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    if item >= len(self):
        raise IndexError

    return 1
```